# Python ImageGrab and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

When I run the following code it opens a new windows with the proper dimensions and it shows the screen properly...but it keeps opening new and new windows on-top and within itself.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

while(True):
    printscreen_pil = ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (0, 40, 400, 340))
    printscreen_numpy = np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(), dtype = 
'uint8').reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1], printscreen_pil.size[0], 3))
    cv2.imshow('window', printscreen_numpy)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

the system is windows 10, 64 bit
python 3.6

Comment: another suggestion use pyscreenshot. PIL only works for windows and mac.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a namedWindow before while. and use the name(first argument) to show the images and it will always show the images in the same window.

```
cv2.namedWindow('window', cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
```

Comment: Welcome. Kindly Accept the Answer.